# Visitor (from DevDemon) - How to logout upon conditionals?

Tags: conditionals, devdemon, zoo-visitor, visitor

I'm using Visitor (for EE v3) and would like to know if there is a way to use the `{exp:visitor:logout return="/mytemplategroup/mytemplate"}` within conditionals?

Because the tag is triggered as soon as the template is parsed, it does not take into account the consitionals I've surrounded it with.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from DevDemon Team : with an embed.

It depends a little on the conditionals because EE parses them at different times in some cases but using a conditional to load an embedded template that contains the Visitor logout tag is working for me.